# Using instanceof with a class Object

Tags: java, class, methods, instanceof

What's the correct syntax to make this work?

```
public boolean isTypeOf(Class type) {
     return this instanceof type;
}
```

I intend to call it with:

```
foo.isTypeOf(MyClass.class);
```

The method will be overriden, otherwise I would just use `instanceof` inplace.

Comment: `this.getClass().equals(type)`?

Comment: Did you know about Class.isInstance(Object)? -  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Note that in Java's grammar, an instance of Class is not a type name - it's a value, and there is no way to get a typename from a value, even with generics (for example, in a generic function you can't say `if(someObject instanceof T)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Class.isInstance(obj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-):

```
public boolean isTypeOf(Class type) {
     return type.isInstance(this);
}
```

This method determines if the given parameter is an instance of the class. This method will also work if the object is a sub-class of the class.

Quoting from the Javadoc:

> This method is the dynamic equivalent of the Java language `instanceof` operator.